# Does burning-in a GPU by stressing it with coil-whine producing load reduce coil-whine?

Tags: gpu, noise, amd-graphics-card, stress-test

It seems the [entire R9 Fiji line, to which my GPU belongs, has this horrible coil-whine problem](http://wccftech.com/amd-radeon-r9-nano-suffering-major-coil-whine-issues-poor-quality-chokes-blamed-reason/). My RMA is worse than my original purchase.

In regards to user-action that can be taken to reduce coil-whine, [Amdmatt, from AMD Communities, states](https://community.amd.com/message/2717224#comment-2717224):

> Find a game or application that produces the most whine and leave it running for 12-24 hours. This may soften the whine over time.

Is this true, and if so what is the reasoning behind how this reduces coil whine?

Update: It's not true for me that burning in as described above will help in any way whatsoever.

Comment: From a quick read of wikipedia this will only make it worse. Glue is sometimes used to dampen the movement reducing the whine but eventually the glue degrades and it worsens again.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Thanks, I will not be trying this then!

Comment: No worries, I'm not an expert but the explaination on wikipedia kind of makes sense that it wouldn't help. It's the metal expanding and contracting - how running it for a long time would help this, I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, coil whine can be caused by a cheap power supply unit - low grade components - or the graphics card itself or both.

Since, as you've already mentioned, this is a known issue for the production line of your graphics card you could do the following:

( - check, just in case, if your psu makes the gpu produce the coil whine)

- get used to it
- do the burn-in or play games with heavy gpu usage
- rma it

Regarding the burn-in, from my personal experience, there won't be much of a difference. My old gtx580, after years of heavy gaming, still produces coil whine.

If you choose the rma option, you are up against the lottery (as you've seen). You could get a new one with the same, less, or even more amount of coil whine...

Comment: Thanks, [the PSU is high-quality](http://www.jonnyguru.com/modules.php?name=NDReviews&op=Story&reid=163). I'm wary of doing the burn in because I don't understand the reasoning and I've already RMAed it :(

Comment: As far as I know, in time (and under normal use) all the electrical components of the gpu will wear and MAY come to a point where they dont produce as much coil whine. That's the theory. With burn-in / stressing the board you should be able to accelerate this process.